# Can a proprietary data store be proxied in Nexus

Tags: continuous-integration, nexus

In our company we have a data store that holds a wide variety of objects. This data store could be seen as a remote repository with a proprietary format. We would to make those objects available in a Nexus Repository Manager in a similar fashion as a remote Maven repository.

I wonder, would it be possible to create a proxy to this non-standard proprietary repository? Our proprietary data store has some version information, that we could map to a standard repository format.

Any help like an example or pointing me to documentation or existing plugins would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can proxy almost anything available via http(s) using a `raw` format proxy in nexus. Now if you want to proxy something that is not maven to a `maven` format, it's not possible.

If you have some version info you can use, I imagine you can create a script that would get a set of artifacts from your company repo and register them correctly using the nexus API in a `maven hosted` repo. That would not be a proxy but a partial async mirror.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I did not think of option to use a raw format proxy. I will further investigate that path. The second option with a maven hosted repo is perhaps easier to implement for us given the nature of our non-standard proprietary repository.